# How to make SpringBoot application and tests work with same path resolving service?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

A custom class `PathConfigurationService` sets a current path of running application to `C:\project`. But since test is inside module x it's `user.dir` system property is different from main application thus returning `C:\project\moduleX` thus making `PathConfigurationService` generate wrong paths to external folder `data` How to make test pickup correct path of `data` folder?

```
- data
  - fileA
  - fileB
- core
  -src/main/java
               -PathConfigurationService
  -src/test/java
               - AbstractTest
 - moduleX
   -src/test/java
              - Test(extending AbstractTest)
```

ModuleX test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplication11.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringBootApplication11.class,
                      initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class Test extends AbstractTest {
    @Autowired
    SpringBootApplication11 app;
}
```

Abstract test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` from `Working directory` input box in IntelliJ Run/Debug Configuration solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the **resources** folder.

In fact, this will let you access your *data* folder the same way from your sources and your tests.

The structure of your project may look like this:

```
Project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- java
        `-- resources
    `-- test
        `-- java
        `-- resources
```

Comment: `data` folder shout stay outside the resources and outside of packaged jar. It is a requirement.